# Mailto link created thought javascript does not work in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, mailto

If I try to set href througth JavaScript in modal, mailto link does not work, but yes in the body part. But if you see when mouseover you can see the correct mailto link. Here there is an example:

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
<br>
<a id="mail_body">Mail me</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <a id="mail_wp">mail me</a>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#mail_wp').attr("href","mailto:example@gmail.com");
  
})

$('#mail_body').attr("href","mailto:example@gmail.com");

</script>
```

Comment: both mailto links work for me.

Comment: I use Chrome and Mailto for Gmail, perhaps is this. what do you use?

Comment: Firefox and Thunderbird on my Win10 pc. I ll give it a try on Chrome

Comment: Tested with chrome and your plugin. The "normal" link doesn't work anymore for me and the one in the modal still opens in thunderbird. I guess the problem comes from the extension rather than your code.